# Dangerous request coming from form -- how to avoid

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to send the body of my web page to an action method so I can save it as a string and later render it partial from another part of the site. I send it like this:

```
var input = 
            {
                id : GetGUIDValue(),
                html : $("body").html(),
                type : 'exposure'
            }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= Url.Action("SaveAnalysis", "Indications") %>",
            data: input,
            success:function(data)
            {

            }
        });
```

I looked up and found this and added it to my page opening statement:

```
ValidateRequest="false"
```

which said it would turn that off, but it isn't. This is a view in MVC2, so maybe there's another way to do it? If not..how can I send the body html of my page to the action so I can save that string in a variable.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Action Code:

```
public ActionResult SaveAnalysis(Guid? id, string html, string type)
        {
            IndicationBase indication = CachedTransactionManager<IndicationBase>.GetCachedTransactions(id.Value);
            if (type == "Exposure")
            {
                indication.Model.ExposureExport = html;
            }
            else if (type == "Prepayment")
            {
                indication.Model.PrepaymentExport = html;
            }
            return Json("");
        }
```

Comment: Could you post the code for your controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running on .NET 4.0? If so, you need to set the requestValidationMode to 2.0. Rick Strahl has a [good article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/746477.aspx) on this on his blog. Basically, you need to do the following:

Set the `requestValidationMode` in your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Decorate your action with `[ValidateInput(false)]`

Comment: Validation mode is not the correct way to handle this.  It does not adjust for cross site scripting and injecting potentially harmful code.  Despite the fact that the author marked this as the solution, it IS NOT the correct approach to handle this and has severe security considerations that are not mentioned in this post, thus the bump down.

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your action method with `[ValidateInput(false)]`

Answer (score 0):

You will want to escape the request using javascript:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

On the C# end you can HTML Encode / Decode for storage and re-rendering.  The issue is with injection attacks, thus C# yells anytime you allow html to be passed in plain text.  When you are aware you will be dealing with HTML you should always encode it before sending it to your controllers.

~Vulgarbinary

**Edit to add new syntax:**

```
var input = 
            {
                id : GetGUIDValue(),
                html : escape($("body").html()),
                type : 'exposure'
            }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= Url.Action("SaveAnalysis", "Indications") %>",
            data: input,
            success:function(data)
            {

            }
        });
```

**Another Edit:**

Originally from:
http://kseesharp.blogspot.com/2008/01/c-equivalent-of-javascript-escape.html

`Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unescape("KC%27s%20trick%20/Hello")` will unescape your string.  Sorry for the delay had to go dig through prior examples I had of this to see what the full unescape syntax was.

Comment: using this on the incoming HTML but its not working --> HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);

Comment: What part isn't working?  Be sure that if you are trying to write it back out you are doing it appropriately:  MvcHtmlString html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(yourstring);  Short of that the Encode / Decode should be working for you.  If not, please set a break point and paste what the HtmlDecode() returns as well as what the input was.  Feel free to edit my post to add the pre/post decode.